# Generalization of consequence of law of cosine

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, monotone-functions, metric-geometry

There is the immediate consequence of the law of cosine stating that when fixing two sidelengths of a triangle and increasing the third, the vertex angle opposite of the third side increases as well. Moreover, this increase of the third side causes the adjacent angles to decrease. I feel like the following generalization of this should hold:

Let $a,b,c$ and $a',b',c$ be the sidelengths of two triangles and let $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ be the vertex angles opposite of the side $c$ (which has the same length in both triangles). If $a+b \leq a'+b'$, then $\gamma \geq \gamma'$.

Simply put, if the sum of the lengths of the adjacent sides of an angle increases (and the opposite length is kept fixed) then this angle decreases.
Ideally, this should hold not only in the plane but in any space where the law of cosine holds, specifically I am thinking of the sphere and hyperbolic space.

[image]

I am having trouble proving this but my gut tells me this has to be true (I did not find anything online, although admittedly I am unsure how to search for this). Intuitively, since $c \leq a+b \leq a'+b'$, the detour through $A$ is "closer" to the shortest connection from $C$ to $D$ than the detour through $B$, so $A$ is closer to the segment $CD$ than $B$ is. This should somehow imply that the angle at $A$ is larger than the angle at $B$ (the angle increases when approaching a segment, with the extreme case of an angle of $\pi$ if the point is on the segment).

I am grateful for any further information!

Comment: If a sum-of-sides is held constant, then the corresponding vertex lies on a particular ellipse with the "base" endpoints as its foci. The vertex angle, then, can vary from $0^\circ$ (when the vertex lies at the end of the major axis) to some maximum (when the vertex lies at the end of the minor axis). Since any two ellipses have angle ranges down to $0^\circ$, there will be overlap in those ranges. Consequently, a bigger sum-of-sides, in and of itself, does not guarantee a smaller angle (although it does guarantee a smaller *maximum* angle).

Answer (score 2):

From [triangle-exterior-angle-theorem](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/triangle-exterior-angle-theorem.html)  \begin{align}\gamma =\gamma''+\alpha'=(\gamma'+\alpha)+\alpha' \,(\alpha\geq0,\alpha'\geq0)\end{align}

\begin{align}\gamma  > \gamma'\, (\alpha \neq0)\end{align}

\begin{align}\gamma = \gamma' \,(\alpha=\alpha'=0)\end{align}
[image]

Comment: Thats beautifully elementary, thank you. Unfortunately, I just read that this theorem does not hold in a more general setting, so i still hope for a more general proof...

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Given $\triangle ABC$ with "vertex" $C$ ...

- As a consequence of the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle), the set of points $C'$ (on the same side of $\overline{AB}$ as $C$) such that $\angle AC'B>\angle ACB$ is bounded by the circumcircular arc $ACB$.
- On the other hand, the set of points $C'$ such that $|AC'|+|BC'|<|AC|+|BC|$ is bounded by the ellipse through $C$ with foci $A$ and $B$.

The circular "larger angle" region never fully covers the elliptical "smaller sum-of-sides" region, so the conjecture is false: the smaller sum-of-sides does not imply a larger angle. $\square$

Note: When $C$ happens to be an endpoint of the minor axis of the ellipse (that is, when $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles with vertex $C$), the "smaller sum-of-sides" region covers the "larger angle" region; so, in this case, a *converse* of the conjecture holds: a larger angle implies a smaller sum-of-sides. But, generally, how the angles compare is independent of how the sums-of-sides compare.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In the other answer, you can see this when the vertex $A$ is pushed "to the left" of $B$, then the argument with $\alpha \geq 0$ does not work anymore. However, for my application I think I can assume that the triangle with the larger angle is contained in the triangle with the smaller angle. In which case your drawing shows this to be correct anyway, if I am not mistaken (the triangle is always contained in the intersection of the red and blue area)..

Comment: If $C'$ is chosen within the interior of $\triangle ABC$, then it's true that $\triangle AC'B$ has a larger angle at $C'$ and a smaller sum-of-sides to $C'$. However, it would not be appropriate to say that the smaller sum-of-sides *implies* the larger angle, or vice-versa. Rather, the properties are *separate* consequences of the independent facts that the interior of $\triangle ABC$ lies within the elliptical region, and that it lies within the circular region.

Comment: Excuse me, can I ask you what graphic software you use to draw figures like the one in this answer?

Comment: @Sebastiano: I use [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org) for my figures.

Comment: @Blue I know Geogebra. But labels and the sans serif font are not there by default. When I want to write a sans serif font I use LaTeX option.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I'm not sure what to tell you. GeoGebra gives me the sans serif font by default. (I use LaTeX for serifed text.) I thought maybe the difference is that I use the desktop (ie, non-web) version of the app ---specifically, the GeoGebra 5 (I don't care for the interface changes of their later releases--- but I just did a quick label-and-text check with the web version and got the san-serif font by default. Maybe there's a font setting somewhere.

Comment: @Sebastiano: By the way, if you've been up-voting a few of my questions all at once ... (1) I appreciate the thought :), but (2) that's called "serial up-voting" and is generally discouraged. (See [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124247).) I don't think anything "bad" happens to the voter (unless it's a fake account created *just* to up-vote things, which isn't the case here), but it's possible that a bunch of up-votes will trigger a site script that'll simply reverse them. So, you may be wasting your time. (I don't "need" more votes anyway. I have all the privileges I want.)

Comment: For the Geogebra I have understood your comment...I have voted your for your kindness and without malice. Being an Italian Sicily citizen the answers were very good and I have given some upvotes for your precious collaboration that I have appreciated very much.